# Are attorneys legally or ethically bound to share evidence in civil cases before complaints are filed?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, tort, attorney-client-privilege

Are attorneys legally or ethically bound to share evidence or discovery materials in civil matters before actual complaints are filed?

Let's say Person A (a non-public figure) suspects Person B (a non-public figure) of a civil tort, such as defamation.

Person A gets Lawyer A to send a cease and desist letter to Person B. Person B shows the letter to their Lawyer (B). Lawyer B asks Person B if they have indeed defamed Person A. Person B says they have and outlines the incidents. Lawyer B determines there is enough evidence that the defamation did damage the reputation of Person A and more than likely resulted in monetarily loses in business for Person A.

Is Lawyer B obligated in any legal or ethical sense to inform Lawyer A of what Person B said before a complaint is filed? Or only after a complaint is filed? And only when discovery takes place? Or would Lawyer B inform Lawyer A out of common and/or professional courtesy?

Answer (score 2):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

There are two issues here:

1. B's "confession" to their lawyer would fall within the definition of legal professional privilege, specifically [litigation privilege](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/topics/civil-litigation/legal-professional-privilege-guide#:%7E:text=Litigation%20privilege%20protects%20communications%20between,existing%20or%20reasonably%20contemplated%20litigation):

> Litigation privilege protects communications between lawyers or their clients and any third party for the purpose of obtaining advice or information in connection with existing **or reasonably contemplated litigation**.

So unless B gives their permission, this cannot be disclosed.

2. A party's duty for disclosure, under [Part 31](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part31#31.1) Civil Procedure Rules, begins once proceedings have started by a claim being issued under [Rule 7.2(1)](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part07#7.2) **unless** [Rule 31.16](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part31#31.16) applies as [section 33](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1981/54/section/33?timeline=false) Supreme Court Act 1981<sup>1</sup> permits disclosure before proceedings have started.

So unless A makes, and is successful with, a section 33 application there is no legal obligation on B for disclosure that is not protected by legal professionalprivilege.

---

<sup>1</sup> Defamation is dealt with as a "media and communications claim" under [Rule 53.1(3)](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part53#IDA1B1HC) in the High Court so the other method of pre-proceedings disclosure at section 52 County Courts Act 1984 does not apply here.

---

<sub>Although tagged [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states), I have answered as per the [Help Centre](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "*we expect and encourage answers dealing with other jurisdictions ... please tag your answer using the tag markdown: [tag: some-tag]*"</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Client B's confession is a privileged communication.

In the absence of special circumstances, Lawyer B is legally and ethically obligated to never share it with Lawyer A.